# python redundant log file

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

Why does the below code create a redundant log file that has no suffix? How can I not create it? Does anyone know, very thanks!

```
import logging.handlers
import re
from time import sleep


formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

fileHandler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler('test', when='s', interval=1, backupCount=2, encoding=None, delay=False, utc=False)
fileHandler.suffix = "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.log"
fileHandler.extMatch = re.compile(r"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}.log$")
fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
consoleHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
logger.addHandler(fileHandler)

for i in range(10):
    sleep(1)
    logger.debug("debug")
    logger.info('info')
    logger.warning("warning")
    logger.error("error")
    logger.critical("critical")
```

OK, it's not a redundant log file, it contain the last log information, but I want it format like "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.log"

Comment: When is the second file created if you debug the application?

Comment: This program will create three files: test, test.2017-08-04_14-33-10.log, test.2017-08-04_14-33-11.log, I don't want to create the file named test

Comment: it's not a redundant log file, it contain the last log information, but I want it format like "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.log"